# Teradata - How to account for missing hours in timestamp when using extract() function

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

I have the following statement to extract the date, hour and number of users from a table in a Teradata DB . . .

```
SELECT
    CAST(end_time AS DATE) AS end_date, 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time) AS end_hour, 
    COUNT(users) AS total_users
FROM table
GROUP BY end_date, end_hour
```

When using the extract() function, my resultset contains missing hours where there is no activity by users over a 24 hour period... I'm wondering is there any technique to account for these missing hours in my resultset?

I can't creat a lookup table to reference as I don't have the necessary permissions to create a table on this DB.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about missing days?

Comment: If you can't create a table you can probably create a temporary table: `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE hours(hh BYTEINT UNIQUE NOT NULL) ON COMMITE PRESERVE ROWS` and then insert 24 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- sys_calendar.calendar to generate the requested dates (change the range as needed)
- WITH RECURSIVE to generate the hours

---

```
with        recursive cte_hours (hr) 
            as
            (
                            select  0      from (select 1) t(c) 
                union all   select  hr + 1 from cte_hours where hr < 23
            )

select      c.calendar_date             as dt
           ,h.hr                        as hr
           ,zeroifnull(t.total_users)   as total_users

from                    sys_calendar.calendar   as c 

            cross join  cte_hours               as h

            left join  (select      cast(end_time as date)      as end_date
                                   ,extract(hour from end_time) as end_hour
                                   ,count(users)                as total_users

                        from        mytable t 

                        group by    end_date
                                   ,end_hour
                        ) t

            on          t.end_date  = c.calendar_date 
                    and t.end_hour  = h.hr 

where       c.calendar_date between current_date - 10 and current_date     

order by    dt,hr
;
```

---

For @GordonLinoff

```
select 0
```

> 0

```
select 1
```

> 1

```
select 0
union all
select 1
```

> [3888] A SELECT for a UNION,INTERSECT or MINUS must reference a table.

```
select 0 from (select 1 as c) t
union all
select 1 from (select 1 as c) t
```

> 0
>   1

or

```
select 0 from (select 1) t(c)
union all
select 1 from (select 1) t(c)
```

> 0
>   1

Comment: when selecting  an extra  column from mytable t in the subquery, the query reverts to leaving out missing hours... For example if I was to select an additional column country from mytable.... I assume this will be a null value too, is there any way of including this for the missing hours?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand

Comment: Sorry, i'll include code extract below to help, sorry if formatting is horrible...

Comment: ,t.country
           ,ZEROIFNULL(t.total_users)   AS total_users
FROM                    sys_calendar.CALENDAR   AS c 
            CROSS JOIN  cte_hours               AS h
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT      CAST(end_time AS DATE)      AS end_date
                                   ,EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time) AS end_hour
                                   ,country
                                   ,COUNT(USER))                AS total_users
                        FROM mytable t 
                                   GROUP BY end_date
,end_hour
,country

Comment: O.K.  - the query does not revert to leaving out missing hours, you just don't get all dates and hours for all countries. I think that what you want to do is to add an additional cross join with the list of the countries

Answer (score 0):

If you want all hours from all days in the database, then you can generate the rows using `cross join` and then use `left join` to bring in results:

```
SELECT d.end_date, 
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time) AS end_hour, 
        COUNT(t.users) AS total_users
FROM (select distinct CAST(end_time AS DATE) AS end_date from table) d CROSS JOIN
     (select distinct EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time) AS end_hour from table) h LEFT JOIN
     table t
     ON t.end_date = d.end_date and t.end_hour = d.end_hour
GROUP BY e.end_date, h.end_hour;
```

If all hours are not represented, you can use an explicit list:

```
SELECT d.end_date, 
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time) AS end_hour, 
        COUNT(t.users) AS total_users
FROM (select distinct CAST(end_time AS DATE) AS end_date from table) d CROSS JOIN
     (select * from (select 0 as end_hour) t UNION ALL 
      select * from (select 1 as end_hour) t UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) h LEFT JOIN
     table t
     ON t.end_date = d.end_date and t.end_hour = d.end_hour
GROUP BY e.end_date, h.end_hour;
```

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . I don't have Teradata on hand.  Is an additional subquery needed `(select * from (select 0 as end_hour) h union all . . . )`?

Comment: See my answer (Bottom)